# Decompress gzip file that contine multiple blocks

Tags: gzip, compression, gzipstream

I have a Gzip file that has multiple blocks.Every block starts with

```
1F 8B 08
```

And ends with

```
00 00 FF FF
```

I tried to decompress the file using 7-Zip and gzip tool in linux ,But I always get an error saying that the file is invalid. 
So I wrote this python script

```
import zlib
CHUNKSIZE=1

f=open("file.gz","rb")
buffer=f.read(CHUNKSIZE)

data=""
r=CHUNKSIZE
d = zlib.decompressobj(16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
while buffer:
  outstr = d.decompress(buffer)
  print(r)
  buffer=f.read(CHUNKSIZE)
  r=r+CHUNKSIZE

outstr = d.flush()
```

I have notice that when it reach to the header of the second block

```
00 00 00 FF FF 1F 8B 08
```

at the point between FF and 1F
the script return

> zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type

I made the size of the chunk to be 1 so the I would know exactly where the problem is.
I know that the problem is not in the file because I have multiple files constructed the same way and they show exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that the problem is not in the file because I have multiple
>   files constructed the same way and they show exactly the same error.

The conclusion is *not* that the problem is not in the file, but rather that the problem is in *all* of your files. Someone either inadvertently or deliberately constructed invalid gzip files. It looks like they did that by using `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` or `Z_FULL_FLUSH` instead of `Z_FINISH` to end each stream before starting another faux gzip stream. A gzip stream ends with a last block followed by an eight-byte gzip trailer containing two check values on the integrity of the uncompressed data.

You can nevertheless continue with decompression, though without the comfort of any integrity checking of the data, by simply picking up with a new instance of `decompressobj` when you get an error and see a new gzip header, `1f 8b 08`.

More importantly you should locate and contact the source of these files and say "Hey, WTF?"